# SQL Server 2012 Passing parameter from main query to the Joined subquery

Tags: t-sql, join, sql-server-2012, subquery

I need to select some settings from some joined tables, but only if `Items ORDER BY EndTime DESC` `ItemID` is among first 1000 Items.

Do do this I built the following Query that, although surely can be improved, works:

```
SELECT  ss.ModuleCode, ss.MaxItems , w.*
FROM Subscriptions      ss
JOIN Sellers            s   ON  s.UID=ss.UID
JOIN Items              i   ON  s.UserID=i.UserID
JOIN Items              ii  ON  i.ItemID=ii.ItemID
JOIN Modules            mo  ON  ss.ModuleCode=mo.ModuleCode
JOIN Settings           w   ON  w.UID=s.UID AND ss.ModuleCode=w.WCode
FULL JOIN GoogleFonts   f   ON  f.FontCode=a.FontFamily
JOIN (  SELECT 
            ItemID
        FROM Items 
        WHERE UserID=@UserID
        ORDER BY EndTime DESC
        OFFSET 0 ROWS
        FETCH FIRST (1000) ROWS ONLY
     ) it ON it.ItemID=i.ItemID

WHERE it.ItemID=@ItemID
AND .....
```

but since MaxItems is not always 1000 and its value is defined by ss.MaxItems, 
I would replace the fixed value of 1000 with the dynamic value of ss.MaxItems, but I haven't find a way to do it:

Although not optimal since makes the query much heavier, I tried putting instead of 1000 a further query with this result:

```
SELECT  ss.ModuleCode, ss.MaxItems , w.*
FROM Subscriptions      ss
JOIN Sellers            s   ON  s.UID=ss.UID
JOIN Items              i   ON  s.UserID=i.UserID
JOIN Items              ii  ON  i.ItemID=ii.ItemID
JOIN Modules            mo  ON  ss.ModuleCode=mo.ModuleCode
JOIN Settings           w   ON  w.UID=s.UID AND ss.ModuleCode=w.WCode
FULL JOIN GoogleFonts   f   ON  f.FontCode=a.FontFamily
JOIN (  SELECT 
            ItemID
        FROM Items 
        WHERE UserID=@UserID
        ORDER BY EndTime DESC
        OFFSET 0 ROWS
        FETCH FIRST (   SELECT ss.MaxItems 
                        FROM Subscriptions  ss
                        JOIN Sellers        s   ON s.UID=ss.UID
                        JOIN Items          i   ON s.UserID=i.UserID
                        JOIN Modules        mo  ON ss.ModuleCode=mo.ModuleCode
                        JOIN Settings       w   ON w.UID=s.UID AND ss.ModuleCode=w.WCode
                        WHERE i.ItemID=@ItemID) ROWS ONLY
      ) it ON it.ItemID=i.ItemID

Where it.ItemID=@ItemID
AND .....
```

but since this returns more than 1 value it is not accepted: limiting to TOP 1 result the latest subquery will work but will not be fully dynamic as required.

Can suggest how to solve or at least suggest the path for the solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `fetch` use `row_number`:

```
   JOIN (SELECT ItemID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY EndTime) as seqnum
         FROM Items it
         WHERE UserID = @UserID 
       ) it
       ON it.ItemID = i.ItemID AND seqnum <= ss.maxitems
```

Comment: Wow! works great!.. 
got error close to ORDER: I assume because PARTITION BY ORDER BY is not allowed:
I amended as PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY EndTime.. or is there a better solution?